# Which filter to use to fetch precipitation data from nomad website?

Tags: weather, gfs, nomad

I want to fetch precipitation data from [nomad Website](http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/) but I don't know which grib filter to use to fetch only preicipation data, can someone tell me which filters to use.

Comment: I think it is variable PRATE

Comment: When i download, file size is zero bytes.

Comment: I think its pratesfc but the unit is kg/m^2/s which i am not that sure what this is..

Answer (score 0):

Try to download only 'PRATE' variable for only 'surface' level. Here is the url:

http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_1p00.pl?file=gfs.t00z.pgrb2.1p00.f003&lev_surface=on&var_PRATE=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.2018070400

I get a grib file of 274kb.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but actually i wanted to get results for 1 degree instead of 0.25 degree and when i am doing same for that i am getting zero bytes file.

Comment: and also what does f001 mean in this type of data ?

Comment: I changed the url for 1 degree and I get a grib file of 28.5KB.f001 stands for the first hour of forecast, so if you take the 00 forecast cycle f001 is the forecast for 1 o' clock in the morning. If you take the 12 cycle f001 is the forecast for 1 o' clock in the afternoon etc.

Comment: Thanks I got that. One more thing I wanted to know how to map the data which we are getting to latitude and longitude, basically given a latitude and longitude I want to get the corresponding data.

Comment: This is a different question and it depends on the programming language you use to read your files. I use R for instance and package rNOMADS `https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rNOMADS/rNOMADS.pdf`. In case you found my answer helpful please consider accepting it `https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers`

Comment: Is there any service present in java for mapping latitude and longitude to data ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Java so I cannot tell.